# How to get bound server address and port programmatically in Java EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, mbeans

At startup we need to get the server address and the http port of the running application. Until now we made it like this:

```
MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName socketBindingMBean = new ObjectName("jboss.as:socket-binding-group=standard-sockets,socket-binding=http");

String  host = (String)  mBeanServer.getAttribute(socketBindingMBean, "boundAddress"),
Integer port = (Integer) mBeanServer.getAttribute(socketBindingMBean, "boundPort"));
```

Everything was fine but after migration from jBoss 7.1.1.Final to 7.1.3.Final we got the problem that the MBean isn't defined at server startup. That means everything is fine if I deploy the application on an **already running** jboss server, but if I start the server and the application is loaded up **during** server start MBeans are not there.

I don't know why but I have the feeling that jBoss makes sure, that out application is started/loaded before most of the MBeans. I had a small look and found out that following Mbeans are loaded after our application:

- jboss.as:interface=..
- jboss.as:socket-binding-group=..
- jboss.as:subsystem=..
- jboss.as:core-service=management.. (some)

So,

- how can I force jBoss to load MBeans before my application?
- is there another way/mbean where I can get my information?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Hui, more than one year ago :) We worked around by delaying the getAttribute-method-call within a new Thread for a few seconds. Doesn't look perfect but runs productive until today.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same issue in JBOSS Wildfly 8.1 . I solved the problem with the code below that worked for me to get server address and http port:

```
//http port
ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().getAttribute(new ObjectName("jboss.as:socket-binding-group=standard-sockets,socket-binding=http"), "port");

//http adress
ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().getAttribute(new ObjectName("jboss.as:interface=public"), "inet-address");
```

Comment: I have an offset of 1 configured, and this is getting 8080 instead of 8081