# How to get bound server address and port programmatically in Java EE for JBoss 6.1 EAP?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, mbeans

I am using following code for getting values of http port for JBoss 6.1 EAP.
This code worked perfectly fine in JBoss 7.1 AS.

Following is the code:

```
MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName socketBindingMBean = new ObjectName("jboss.as:socket-binding-group=standard-sockets,socket-binding=http");
Integer port = (Integer) mBeanServer.getAttribute(socketBindingMBean, "boundPort"));
```

This code works fine if I deploy the WAR after the server has started, but it fails to work during start up.
Is there a change in which JBoss loads its modules? How can I get this information at startup?

Comment: I also came to know that there is a similar question raised before. Can some one help me out how it was resolved?

Answer (score 1):

this is normal while the sockets and ports is not initialized yet and it will after the server is run successfuly then you could read it ,
i would suggest to use configuration file of JBoss and keep one prt fixed always for your aplication then you will know it always ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My requirement is to fill up these details at startup. At first, we did the same, but we want to eliminate this file altogether. Is there any way to delay the deployment until server initializes these values?

Comment: This is a valid question. There is no need to down vote it.

Comment: Similar Question has been asked     [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741004/how-to-get-bound-server-address-and-port-programmatically-in-java-ee